# Alternative to Gundo tree that avoid messing up my window layout

Tags: undo-redo

There are several plugins which open a window on the left or right side, [nerdtree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree) and [tagbar](https://github.com/preservim/tagbar) being just to examles.

And then there's [gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim), the functionality of which is invaluable, but lord... it just messes up all my windows!

[image: asciicast]

Is there an alternative to it which behaves a bit better from this point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) for a while without any real issues.